# How to retry failed Cron scheduled job multiple times

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

Using QuartzScheduler I am using following snippet to create CronTrigger:

```
 TriggerBuilder
      .Create()
      .WithIdentity(schedule.job + "-" + schedule.application)
      .WithCronSchedule(schedule.CronExpression)
      .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15)))
      .WithDescription(schedule.CronExpression)
      .WithPriority(1)
      .Build();
```

Following snippet to create Job

```
 JobBuilder
      .Create(jobType)
      .WithIdentity(schedule.job + "-" + schedule.application)
      .WithDescription(jobType.Name)
      .SetJobData(new JobDataMap(map))
      .UsingJobData(keys)
      .Build();
```

When this job fails, I want to retry job specified number of times, so I have found that there is [SimpleTrigger](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html) class and using following snippet for it:

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .StartAt(myTimeToStartFiring) 
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
    .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
    .WithRepeatCount(10)) 
    .ForJob(myJob) // identify job with handle to its JobDetail itself                   
    .Build();
```

But it does not seem to fire myJob. What could be the issue?
There is a chance that cron scheduled job may execute few times sucessfully and fail on other occasions, I need to retry only the failed ones and report it accordingly in history.

Comment: `.WithRepeatCount(10)` is not meant for 'Retry on Error'. It just repeats your job 10 times. In your case the job runs every 10 seconds once and after it runs 10 times, it will stop. As i remember right there is no inbuilt way to retry a job a number of times after it fails, you can only trigger a execute after a failed job. A combination of Quartz and [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) could be a solution. I don't know why your job is not executing, you need to provide more code to explore that.